# Is it possible using the GAE Logs API to retrive front-end logs only?

Tags: google-app-engine

How can we we send a query to the Log API such that it only retrieves logs from the front end and not the backends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what runtime you're asking about, but looking at the Python source for SDK 1.8.8 you have the following arguments for the `google.appengine.api.logservice.fetch` function:

```
module_versions: A list of tuples of the form (module, version), that
  indicate that the logs for the given module/version combination should be
  fetched.  Duplicate tuples will be ignored.  This kwarg may not be used
  in conjunction with the 'version_ids' kwarg.
```

(This isn't yet reflected in the [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions#fetch))

This does not mean you can directly access front-end logs, but if you [convert your app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/converting) from using backends to using two named modules, one for front-end requests and another for backend work, you'll be able to fetch the logs of each independently.

Comment: Yeah, this is one possibility. The conversion to Modules makes this a no go for us right now as it will require refactoring of our front end. Also the version number of our server changes with every deployment and I would like to not have to maintain this mapping.

Comment: I just dug up [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/BTKQP_4UAsI/kwLjDrwqr0oJ) from the App Engine google group, it seems to suggest you can retrieve backend logs by using the backend name as the version. You need the opposite functionality, so have you tried filtering by the latest version in the Logs API to see if it returns just front-end logs?